# Three.js raycaster.setFromCamera error

Tags: three.js

I'm getting a TypeError while setting up raycasting, specifically raycaster.setFromCamera.

I'm using mostly boilerplate code from [this example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_voxelpainter).

I'm calling raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera ) from a mouseDown function. Anyone know what might be happening?

code on github: https://github.com/mitchellhart/threejsh/blob/master/js/index.js

error message: 'Uncaught TypeError: raycaster.setFromCamera is not a function'

Comment: you need to show the exact code that is producing the error and the exact error.

Comment: which version of three.js are you using?

Comment: release 73. minified

Comment: actually just saw your index.html. you are using r68 and I believe `setFromCamera()` did not exist back then.

Comment: You are right there, this problem is solved. Do you want to create an answer I can mark? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Update your threejs file to a more recent version.